# How to find maximum value after a group by and joins?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, max

How would you get the maximum revenue for username using two joins and group by? I'm expecting to get one row that is username and the maximum revenue. The reason why it needs to be sum first is because a user may have multiple different videos giving him/her revenue. Thus, the revenue must be aggregated.

I've tried this:

```
SELECT first_username||' '||last_username as username, max(sum(revenue)) max_revenue
FROM uploader
JOIN video on video.uploader_id= uploader.uploader_id
JOIN users on uploader.user_id = users.user_id
GROUP BY first_username||' '||last_username;
```

This results in a "not a single-group group function" error. Is there an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: What's that expected to do? (Each user only has one sum(revenue).)

Comment: I just wanted the maximum revenue and the user's name who corresponds to this revenue amount basically.

Comment: I see. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: oracle/sql_developer

Comment: `ORDER BY sum_revenue DESC`, and put `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` at the end.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER/RANK are calculated *after* aggregation

Comment: Where does alias `uploader` come from? It is not defined in the query.

Comment: I made the change, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the query below, I am using the `RANK` analytic function to return any content creators that have the maximum revenue. If 2 or more content creators have the same revenue then they will both be returned.  If you only ever want 1 row returned, then you can change the `RANK` function to the `ROW_NUMBER` function.

```
WITH
    sample_data (first_username, last_username, revenue)
    AS
        (SELECT 'Marques', 'Brownlee', 4030 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Marques', 'Brownlee', 8724 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Linus', 'Sebastian', 5731 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Linus', 'Sebastian', 7372 FROM DUAL)
SELECT username, sum_revenue AS max_revenue
  FROM (SELECT username, sum_revenue, RANK () OVER (ORDER BY sum_revenue DESC) AS revenue_rank
          FROM (  SELECT first_username || ' ' || last_username     AS username,
                         SUM (revenue)                              AS sum_revenue
                    FROM /*content_creators
                         JOIN video ON video.uploader_id = uploader.uploader_id
                         JOIN users ON uploader.user_id = users.user_id*/
                         sample_data
                GROUP BY first_username || ' ' || last_username))
 WHERE revenue_rank = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Reason of error is you are using nested aggregation,

Use one level sub query to get the `max` value again

```
SELECT username,max(revenue_total) max_revenue
  FROM
(
    SELECT first_username||' '||last_username as username, sum(revenue) revenue_total
    FROM uploader
    JOIN video on video.uploader_id= uploader.uploader_id
    JOIN users on uploader.user_id = users.user_id
    GROUP BY first_username||' '||last_username
)
GROUP BY username;
```

**Edit: Improvised answer**

Above query does solve the error but for this use case is not really useful. So we can just do like,

```
SELECT username,revenue_total max_revenue
  FROM
(
    SELECT first_username||' '||last_username as username, sum(revenue) revenue_total
    FROM uploader
    JOIN video on video.uploader_id= uploader.uploader_id
    JOIN users on uploader.user_id = users.user_id
    GROUP BY first_username||' '||last_username
)
ORDER BY revenue_total DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

Note: Can also be done without the inner sub query but I prefer for readability purpose.

Comment: Is it possible to get the row with the highest revenue? That gives me all the rows.

Comment: @QMan5, do you mean irrespective of username ?

Comment: The accepted answer I think give you exactly the same. But if you don't want to use `rank` and your are on Oracle 12c then you can use like `order by max(revenue_total) desc limit 1` with the query I put.

Comment: When I put that on the end I get "SQL command not properly ended", do you know why that might be happening?

Comment: My mistake...it's Oracle I forgot in a moment...it should be `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` instead `limit`